# How do I maintain high-level documentation along with phpdoc generated documentation?

Tags: documentation, phpdoc

For my first open source project ([shameless plug: mtChart](http://mtchart.googlecode.com)) I currently have two different types of documentations:

- HTML files generated by Doxygen from the phpdoc-comments within the code
- The wiki pages on Google Code (Or simply put: Additional text files)

The Doxygen files are really great, but I miss the possiblity to add 'high-level' documentation: Tutorials, examples, overview over the system, roadmaps etc.

How do I combine these two in an automated manner so I can keep the code documentation updated with somehow automatically including the rest of the texts?

(I'm willing to move away from Doxygen if necessary.)

Comment: Are you talking about generating tutorials on how to use classes from annotations in code? If so, that sounds like a cool and interesting project. You could even infer various things. Sounds cool.

Comment: Yes and no. I don't want to generate tutorials, I've already written some and would like to combine those somehow with the documentation automatically...

Comment: Into a consistent set of texts (HTML, txt, anything...). 

Like I said, Doxygen or phpDocumentor produces perfectly adequate documentation of the code. I wonder if I can add arbitrary texts to this documentation in an automated manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use phpdoc-style you're obviously aware that you could do the examples, tutorials etc right inside it and provide links to external content like roadmaps as necessary.
It is not ideal but definitely works and gives you a consistent and useful documentation. Just use some formating inside your comments for easy-to read text and @see for the links.
You might also consider using inline tags but I am not sure you need to go as far as that from the start.

```
/**
 * @todo Need to move to the main framework
 *
 *        class: RegistrationPeer extends AbstractPeer
 *      package: Registration
 *   subpackage: Peer
 *
 *       method: findByUserId($userId)
 *   visibility: public
 *       static: yes
 *
 *         file: xxx
 *
 *        class: Registration extends AbstractModel
 *      package: Registration
 *   subpackage: Model
 *
 * Sample usage:
 * <code>
 * <?php
 *     $userId = $sessionManager->getRegUid();
 *     $registration = RegistrationPeer::findByUserId($userId);
 * ?>
 * </code>
 *
 * @see AbstractPeer
 * @see http://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=xxxx&hl=en
 *
 * @author xxx
 */
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, I wasn't really aware of all the phpdoc-possibilities. Guess I'll hit the documentation once more... :-)